# Does google compute api support promises?

Tags: java, node.js, google-api, promise, google-compute-engine

Examples given at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/addresses/list) are with callbacks. I would like to know if I can use promises.

Comment: Seems the API doesn't support promise natively as the NodeJS example is written with callback. But you may be able to convert it to promise.

Answer (score 1):

This might help -- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Or this https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node

Side note -- I am assuming node.js since your question is tagged as such. However its also tagged java, so no idea which you're actually looking for. Note that an HTTP API doesn't support/not support promises. Promises are a pattern for handling async calls on the client, based on your HTTP-request framework of choice.

Hope that helps.